# Hot/Cold Observable, multiply subscribers

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How I could convert the `MainEngine` Observable to Cold ? from this example:

```
    public IObservable<int> MainEngine
    {
        get
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int maxValue = rnd.Next(20);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Max value is: " + maxValue.ToString());

            return (from sinlgeInt in Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue)
                    select sinlgeInt).ToObservable();
        }
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        // 1
        MainEngine.Subscribe(
                onNext: (item) => { System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Value is: " + item.ToString()); }
        );

        // 2
        MainEngine.Subscribe(
                onNext: (item) => { System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Gonna put it into XML: " + item.ToString()); }
        );
    }
```

Question 1: On subscriber 1 and subscriber 2 I get a different results but I want both of them receive the same results.

Question 2: From the point in time when I add the **second** subscriber both of them continue to receive the same results.

Comment: Because this is being scheduled on the same thread, it makes no difference. (1) is going to complete before (2) starts.

Comment: Minor point, and it probably only happened because you simplified from a more complex real-world example, but
"from sinlgeInt in Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue) select sinlgeInt"
could be replaced with
"Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first question, the issue is that the observers are not subscribing to the same `IObservable` since you call the getter twice.

Assigning the `IObservable` to a local variable seems to fix the issue:

```
IObservable<int> mainEngine = MainEngine;

mainEngine.Subscribe(onNext: (item) => { /* ... */ });
mainEngine.Subscribe(onNext: (item) => { /* ... */ });
```

Regarding your second question, if you would like to share a subcription to a single `IObservable`, you can use the `Publish` method:

```
IConnectableObservable<int> published = MainEngine.Publish();

published.Subscribe(onNext: (item) => { Console.WriteLine(item + " on observer 1"); });
published.Subscribe(onNext: (item) => { Console.WriteLine(item + " on observer 2"); });

published.Connect();
```

The two subscribers will then see the results from the `IObservable` in an interleaved fashion:

```
0 on observer 1
0 on observer 2
1 on observer 1
1 on observer 2
etc.
```

You can also subscribe new observers after the call to Subscribe, after which point all subscribers will see the same events. You can modify your example to test this, by running your observable on a new thread and introducing a delay:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int maxValue = rnd.Next(20);

    /* Zip with Observable.Interval to introduce a delay */
    IObservable<int> mainEngine = Observable.Range(0, maxValue, Scheduler.NewThread)
        .Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)), (a, b) => a);

    /* Publish the observable to share a subscription between observers */
    IConnectableObservable<int> published = mainEngine.Publish();

    /* Subscribe the first observer immediately, events are not yet being observed */
    published.Subscribe(onNext: (item) => { Console.WriteLine(item + " on observer 1"); });

    /* Start pushing events to the first observer */
    published.Connect();

    /* Wait one second and then subscribe the second observer */
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    published.Subscribe(onNext: (item) => { Console.WriteLine(item + " on observer 2"); });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You will see one second's worth of events only on the first observer, and then both observers will see each event simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

Your observable is already **cold**. If you take an instance of the observable each and every time you subscribe to it you get the same values.

The only way that it looks like it is **hot** is that if you make multiple calls to `MainEngine` you get back **different** observable instances. But that doesn't make them truly **hot**.

Effectively you have created a **cold observable factory**.

To make the `MainEngine` method truly hot you need to add a `Defer` call, like so:

```
public IObservable<int> MainEngine
{
    get
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int maxValue = rnd.Next(20);

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(
                "Max value is: " + maxValue.ToString());

            return Observable.Range(0, maxValue);
        });
    }
}
```

Also note that I changed `Enumerable.Range` to `Observable.Range` and removed the call to `.ToObservable()`.

In order to now actually make it hot here's what to do:

```
var hotObservable = MainEngine.Publish().RefCount();
```

This effectively means that when you have more than one observable subscribed at the same time they will share the underlying observable. When none are subscribed the underlying observable goes away and is only created when a new observer subscribes.

Keep in mind that your implementation of `MainEngine` defaults to running using the `Scheduler.Immediate` so you won't see the benefit of this code until you change the observable to run on a different thread.

I hope this helps.